# Lazy Loading of Google Maps library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, lazy-loading

I'm aware of Google maps libraries as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) and I'm currently loading them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,weather&sensor=false"></script>
```

Problem is my map page lets users do a lot of different things and I'm now using 4 libraries.
What I would like is only include the "basic" Google Maps javascript when the page loads and lazy-load each library only when required (e.g. when the user wants to view the weather).

Is this possible at all, without reloading the whole Google Maps API each time I need a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see where you are coming from but:

a) I don't know that the library was intended to be used that way, so even if you could get it to work, it would likely not be guaranteed to be stable, and

b) that call you have above pulls a short script which then calls a function called getScript and passes it this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,weather&sensor=false

If you omit the "weather" part from the call it gives you, unsurprisingly, this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false

The difference in size between those two files is 0.6k.  Less when you consider compression.

I doubt you'll save any significant time by trying to load them separately.  Overall, it's probably faster to load them together anyway because of the per-request latency involved.